# How can I pass the current user to a custom form validator?

Tags: django, validation

[Two scoops of Django](http://twoscoopspress.com/products/two-scoops-of-django-1-6) advises to make a custom validator for a form as follows:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField()
    repo_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


def validate_repo_existance(value):
     # Validate repo existance.
     # This needs the Github account which is bound 
     # to the user account though.


class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["repo_name"].validators.append(validate_repo_existance)

    class Meta:
         model = MyModel
```

Is there any way to pass the user that is on the form page to the custom validator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I was looking for:

*views.py*

```
form = MyModelForm(request.user)  # when unbound

form = MyModelForm(request.user, data=request.POST)  # when bound
```

*validators.py*

```
class RepoValidator(object):
    def __init__(self, user):
        self.user = user

    def __call__(self, value):
        #self.user and value are accessible from here
```

*forms.py*

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["repo_name"].validators.append(RepoValidator(user))

    class Meta:
         model = MyModel
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["repo_name"].validator.append(validate_repo_existance)
```

And pass the user from your view where you instantiate the form:

```
form = MyModelForm(request.user)  # when unbound

form = MyModelForm(request.user, data=request.POST)  # when bound
```

This pattern is used for any other data that you need to pass to a Django form.

Comment: Cool, but how can I pass that `user` in the `__init__` method to the `validate_repo_existance`? It seems you can only pass a function object without arguments.

Comment: For a simple field validation `clean_fieldname()` method would suffice, if you are validating based on values in multiple fields use the `clean()` method. If you need to use validators (btw, you probably meant `self.validators.fields["repo_name"].append(validate_repo_existance)`, you skipped the `validators` part) you can use a class that gets the user in the constructor. See how Django does this: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/fields.py#L212

Comment: Thanks for providing me with important clues. Also, thanks for the correction, I forgot to write the `validators` attribute in my question (but it was in my real code).

Comment: I made a mistake myself, it's: `self.fields["repo_name"].validators.append(validate_repo_existance)` :)

Answer (score 1):

The current user is stored in the request object, and can be accessed with `request.user`. You can pass this user as an argument into the form.